# cucumber test file download

Tags: cucumber

Anybody have idea how to test file download using cucumber?

Comment: Need a bit more information.  Is this a batch app, a website, are you using Watir or similar API?  What exactly relating to file download are you trying to test?

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me based when using send_data like so `send_data(data, :filename => "inventory_#{Date.today.to_s}.csv", :disposition => 'attachment')`

Probably not best way to write the step, but it worked!

```
Then /^I should receive a file(?: "([^"]*)")?/ do |file|
  result = page.response_headers['Content-Type'].should == "application/octet-stream"
  if result
    result = page.response_headers['Content-Disposition'].should =~ /#{file}/
  end
  result
end
```

Answer (score 11):

I found [this](http://makandra.com/notes/931-test-a-download-s-filename-with-cucumber) to be a convenient way of testing for downloads, its a naiv way just testing for the headers put for most of the time its reasonable.

If you are using capbybara then put the following inside your step_definitions.rb

```
    Then /^I should get a download with the filename "([^\"]*)"$/ do |filename|
       page.response_headers['Content-Disposition'].should include("filename=\"#{filename}\"")
    end
```

Inside your feature you can now do:

```
    When I follow "Export as ZIP"
    Then I should get a download with the filename "contacts_20110203.zip"
```

Cheers

Comment: Tried but fired this exception `Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError Exception: Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError`. Any suggestion?

Comment: I only tested it with rack-test as driver. What are you using, Selenium ?

Comment: yeah.. selenium. Any Suggestion?

Comment: use the @rack_test tag for that specific scenario

Comment: Hi folks recently I have faced same issue. I have solved the problem by the help of these comments.Thank you very much :)

Comment: Would be nice to test with with selenium, anyone know why it doesn't work with `js: true`?

Answer (score 1):

I run selenium through chrome, when I'm testing that the csv has downloaded, I use the following in Ruby:

```
Then /^I should get a downloaded file for fleet: "(.*?)"$/ do |export|       
    puts Dir["C:/Users/**/Downloads/fleet_#{export}_export_all_*.csv"].last
end
```

It simply looks in the default download directory and confirms that the file is there and outputs the filename within cmd.

Answer (score 1):

On chrome I do it by opening the page: `chrome://downloads` and then use the shadow dom to retrieve the downloaded files:

```
document
  .querySelector('downloads-manager')
  .shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloads-list')
  .getElementsByTagName('downloads-item');
```

The downloaded files list also contain information such as file path and download date.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome you can set the capability providing chrome options. Refer below code

```
      String downloadFilepath = "path to specify download location e.g. C:\\Downloads";      
      Map<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
      chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
      DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();       
      cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

then you can use exists() method of java.io.File to make sure if file exists.

```
    File file = new file(downloadFilepath+filename);
    assert file.exists() : "File not downloaded";
```