# How to test file download with rspec 1.3.0/capybara 0.3.9/selenium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara

Hi friends I want to test file download in capybara.

I have tried

```
page.response_headers['Content-Type']
```

But it raises Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError exception.

I have also tried

```
page.driver.browser.switch_to.alert.text
```

It fails with the message 'No alert is present'

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cucumber test file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255250/cucumber-test-file-download)

Comment: Yes friend. Just now I have solved this by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255250/cucumber-test-file-download/534130#answer-6533829

Comment: I have used rake_test driver and tested the response headers to ensure file download.

Answer (score 12):

I tested that when I click on a link I should receive *.pdf file.

```
click_on "link_to_pdf"
page.response_headers['Content-Type'].should eq "application/pdf"
```

It doesn't work with selenium, so better to specify not javascript driver. I am sure that it works with RackTest.

```
feature "Download pdf", :js => false do
end
```

Comment: Wow, setting `js: false` worked! But why?? "It doesn't work with selenium", anyone know why, as I need JS on my view to run!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement something similar and spend lots of hours. Finally I have some solution, maybe it fit for you as well.

Gemfile:

```
#source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.36.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'rename'
gem 'sprockets',                             '3.6.3'
gem 'responders',           '~> 2.0' 
gem 'inherited_resources'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
    gem 'capybara',           '2.8.1'
    gem 'rspec',              '3.5.0'
    gem 'rspec-rails',     '~> 3.4'
    gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
    gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 3.0', require: false
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.5.0'
end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

require 'shoulda/matchers'

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end

config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

require 'download_helper'

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile['browser.download.dir'] = DownloadHelpers::PATH.to_s
  profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2

  profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = 'text/csv'
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, :profile => profile)
end


RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups

    config.include Capybara::DSL


=begin
  config.filter_run_when_matching :focus

  config.example_status_persistence_file_path = "spec/examples.txt"

  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  if config.files_to_run.one?
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  config.profile_examples = 10

  config.order = :random

  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

test/test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'capybara/rails'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
    include ApplicationHelper

    def is_logged_in?
        !session[:user_id].nil?
    end

    # Logs in a test user.
    def log_in_as(user, options = {})
        password = options[:password] || 'password'
        remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
        if integration_test?
            post login_path, session: { email:user.email, password: password, remember_me: remember_me }
        else
            session[:user_id] = user.id
        end
    end

    private

        # Returns true inside an integration test.
        def integration_test?
            defined?(post_via_redirect)
        end

end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL

  # Reset sessions and driver between tests
  # Use super wherever this method is redefined in your individual test classes
  def teardown
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    Capybara.use_default_driver
  end
end
```

spec/download_helper.rb

```
module DownloadHelpers
  TIMEOUT = 1
  PATH    = Rails.root.join("tmp/downloads")

  extend self

  def downloads
    Dir[PATH.join("*")]
  end

  def download
    downloads.first
  end

  def download_content
    wait_for_download
    File.read(download)
  end

  def wait_for_download
    Timeout.timeout(TIMEOUT) do
      sleep 0.1 until downloaded?
    end
  end

  def downloaded?
    !downloading? && downloads.any?
  end

  def downloading?
    downloads.grep(/\.part$/).any?
  end

  def clear_downloads
    FileUtils.rm_f(downloads)
  end
end
```

spec/mpodels/spec.rb

```
  describe 'Download file' do

    specify do
      visit '/createfile'

      click_on 'create file'

            page.response_headers['Content-Type'].should == "text/lfile"
            header = page.response_headers['Content-Disposition']
            header.should match /^attachment/
            header.should match /filename=\"temp.txt\"$/
       end
    end
```