# cucumber file download with @javascript tag feature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, capybara

I am using cucumber to test my application(which is in Rails). Now, I am having problem to test downloading file. I am using backbone so I am putting @javascript tag at every feature. I have gone through the solutions which is given in stackoverflow like : [cucumber test file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255250/cucumber-test-file-download) but they are in rack-test. I want to know that how to click on file download box when we have @javascript in cucumber? I was trying to verify the response headers like : `page.response_headers['Content-Type'].should == "text/csv"` but it shows that its not supported in capybara.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you use Selenium as a driver which is default driver in case of @javascript.

Selenium [doesn't provide cross-browser solution for this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=95). You want to test your application, not browser's native download windows so you should tell browser to autosave downloaded files.

If [you use Firefox](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#Tweaking_Firefox_preferences):

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  profile['browser.download.dir'] = "/path-to-folder/webdriver-downloads"
  profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf" # content-type of file that will be downloaded
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox, profile: profile)
end
```

If [you use Google Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings#Tweaking_profile_preferences):

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  profile['download.prompt_for_download'] = false
  profile['download.default_directory'] = "/path/to/dir"
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, profile: profile)
end
```

Then you click link (which invokes file download) and file is saved to specified directory.